# how to understand the value !false in maven profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I encounter a very strange question when using profile in maven.The code segment is below.

```
<profile>
        <id>update-jboss-as</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>release</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>ddd-djn</module> 
            <module>jboss-as</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

I have not set `release` property, so this profile can't be activated, the module will not execute, now everything is ok.

**but** when I add a code line and the code segment as below:

```
 <profile>
        <id>update-jboss-as</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>release</name>
                <value>!false</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>ddd-djn</module> 
            <module>jboss-as</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

the new added content is `<value>!false</value>`

in my mind, the profile will not be activated either. It will be activated only there exist `release` property **and** its value is not `false`, and here I have not set the `release` property at all. Strangely, in practice this profile is activated.

**Question**: I don't know why this happens, maybe the value `!false` has unique meaning?

Comment: can you try to rename the property name? I kind of recall "release" is a special property (but I cannot find any info on it... dunno why I got such memory :P ) , Or, in your POM or parent POMs, are there any "release" property defined?  I guess you may ask Maven to output the effective POM to check about it

Comment: @AdrianShum it's a bug, based on my investigation. Check my answer.

Comment: @AdrianShum I have to rectify, following a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6094) I reported, it's not a bug but rather wrong doc

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks to this question (and the related [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-293) and the active community behind it) the official Maven documentation has been clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is reproducible with any name and value:

```
<profile>
    <id>test-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>something</name>
            <value>!a</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    ...
</profile>
```

The profile above will actually be active by default. This is in contradiction with the official [Maven profile documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) on the `!true` value example:

> The following profile will be activated when the system property "debug" **is defined** with a value which is not "true".

Note: bold is mine.

Since such a property name (any) would not be inherited by a potential default property defined in the [super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html), then indeed it is **not defined** and as such it should not match the condition. However, it seems like the `!` operator plays an important role adding to the rule also the case to activate the profile when the property is not specified (as such, not being specified would also mean it did not provide the value, matching the `value` condition, but indeed slightly changing the `name` part).

---

If the mechanism is still implemented by the [`SystemPropertyProfileActivator`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-compat/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/profiles/activation/SystemPropertyProfileActivator.java), deprecated but not documented by which componenet it was replaced, if already replaced, then the bug is confirmed by the following shortened code:

```java
ActivationProperty property = activation.getProperty();

if ( property != null ) {
    String name = property.getName();
    boolean reverseName = false;

    String sysValue = properties.getProperty( name );

    String propValue = property.getValue();
    if ( StringUtils.isNotEmpty( propValue ) ) {
        boolean reverseValue = false;
        if ( propValue.startsWith( "!" ) ) {
            reverseValue = true;
            propValue = propValue.substring( 1 );
        }

        // we have a value, so it has to match the system value...
        boolean result = propValue.equals( sysValue );

        if ( reverseValue ) {
            return !result;
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is: the `sysValue` real property value by the defined `name` is not taken into account, it will be `null` in this specific case. However, its check on `equals` will return `false`, but then the further check on `reverseValue` would turn it to `true`, regardless of the existence of the `name` property and effectively activating the profile in this case.

---

**Update**
Following the related [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6094) I reported on the official Maven JIRA, the issue has been clarified: **it is not a bug but rather wrong documentation**.
Hence the expected behavior is indeed to have the profile active by default with such a configuration.

Comment: I created an [official bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6094) for that.

Comment: Thanks :) and congrats on reaching 10k!

Comment: @Tunaki thanks! and thanks for having clarified the official doc!